# What kind of db storage does websphere MQ use

Tags: messaging, ibm-mq

What kind of database does websphere MQ come with? A DB2 db? or a local file system based db. It needs to have some form of persistent storage because if it receives a message on the queue and the listeners are down then it needs to persist the message until the listeners are back up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224362/how-are-websphere-mq-messages-stored-to-allow-persistence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, on distributed systems, WMQ uses a proprietary storage format for both the rolling transaction logs and the safe-store queue files.  IBM does not release any information regarding these files, as the formats and contents are subject to chance without notice between releases and versions as necessary to support new features and functions.

Someone else can provide similar information for z/OS systems.

Comment: Does it support RDBMS stores instead of local disk?

Comment: Again, for distributed systems it does not.  For z/OS specific information, I have to defer to others more familiar with the implementation for that platform.